# .NET Regex for a directive followed by some comma separated numbers

Tags: regex, f#, string-parsing

I'm trying to write a regex in F# that will match things like this

```
.float -.05, 2.4
.float 31.1234
.float -0.5, 1.0, 1.1
```

I'm trying something like this

```
let matchFloat input =
    let matches = Regex(@"(\.float )?(?<float>[+-]?\d*\.\d+)").Matches(input)
    ([for m in matches -> m.Groups.["float"].Value, matches.Count > 0)
```

Which kind of works, but I have the same thing for .double and whatever the first one in my match expression is will be the one that gets matched - since I do an "occurs 0 or 1 times", it means the strings of floating point numbers following either directive will be treated the same.

So how do I make sure the .float is there, without doing input.StartsWith(...)?  I know there is way I can write this regex so that it will match appropriately, and m.Groups.["float"].Value will return only what I need without having remove spaces or commas after the fact.

I have been messing with this thing for hours and just can't get it to do what I want.  I've tried using the lookbehind/lookahead stuff, and a few other things, but no luck.

Comment: So should it match the first pair of numbers after .float or all of them?

Comment: It should match all of them

Comment: And .float is mandatory to occur?

Comment: yea - I'll also have .double, and I need to be able to differentiate between them.

Comment: Why input.StartsWith(...) is a bad solution? It's definitely more readable and easier to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this gets you well on your way to [step 1 of fixing a Linux machine](http://theoatmeal.com/blog/fix_computer)

You can use positive lookbehind combined with alternation to capture either `.float` or `.decimal` at the start of the line into a group, then check which one was captured. The lookbehind itself does not contribute to the primary capture, so the numerical digits are still the only thing in "group 0".

Then my favorite tricksy bit - by adding a `.*` within the lookbehind (after `float` or `decimal`), you can successfully return multiple matches from the input string, each sharing the initial `.float` or `.decimal`, but then each zooming forward to capture a different set of digits.

Putting a bow on it with a little DU type to represent the two cases:

```
type DataPoint =
    | Float of string
    | Decimal of string

let parse input =
    let patt = "(?<=^\.((float)|(decimal)).*(,?\s+))[+-]?\d*\.\d+(?=\s*(,|$))"
    Regex.Matches(input, patt)
    |> Seq.cast<Match>
    |> Seq.map (fun m ->
        match (m.Groups.[2].Success, m.Groups.[3].Success) with
        | (true, false) -> Float(m.Value)
        | (false, true) -> Decimal(m.Value)
        | _ -> failwith "??")
    |> List.ofSeq

// positive cases
parse ".float -.05, 2.4"        // [Float "-.05"; Float "2.4"]
parse ".float 31.1234"          // [Float "31.1234"]
parse ".float -0.5, 1.0, 1.1"   // [Float "-0.5"; Float "1.0"; Float "1.1"]
parse ".decimal 123.456, -22.0" // [Decimal "123.456"; Decimal "-22.0"]

// negative cases, plucks out valid bits
parse ".decimal xyz,,.., +1.0, .2.3.4, -.2 "  // [Decimal "+1.0"; Decimal "-.2"]
parse ".float 1.0, 2.0-, 3."                  // [Float "1.0"]
```

Note that I've just relied on the group numbers, you might want to be more careful and used named groups.

Also worth noting that .NET is [one of the only regex environments](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that supports full alternation and `.*` matching within a lookbehind, so this might not be portable.

**Edit:** I hardened the pattern somewhat against negative input based on feedback.  Still not bulletproof.

Comment: Actually, your Regex also matches strings like ".float 5.4.3.,.0"

Comment: That is excellent feedback and totally true! Update incoming.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't see any reason why in this case Regex is useful at all. Using string functions and System parsing functions is more readable and type safe way to parse the input. Borrowing DataPoint from @latkin's answer:

```
open System

type DataPoint =
    | Float of float
    | Decimal of decimal

let listparse parser mapper = 
    List.choose (fun f -> match parser f with true, v -> Some (mapper v) | _ -> None)

let parse (input: string) =
    match Array.toList (input.Split([|',';' '|])) with
    | ".float"::rest -> rest |> listparse Double.TryParse Float
    | ".decimal"::rest -> rest |> listparse Decimal.TryParse Decimal
    | _ -> []
```

And using extra parameters in .TryParse() methods you can easily handle more complex floating point input formats like exponent notation (1.3E5 for example)

Answer (score -1):

try this  `\.float [+-]?[0-9\., ]+` and also refer this (http://regex101.com/r/kW6zZ1/1)

Comment: This has a few issues: 1. It matches bogus strings like `.float ,,,,,`, `.float 5.4.3.,.0` etc.  2. It does not capture the entirety of valid strings like `.float 1.5, -2.5`  3. It provides no way to extract the individual digit groups, as OP has made clear is the goal.